# Three.js raycaster causing animation to not show

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have created a 3D animation in webGL using Three.js and I am trying to create a sphere object to be shot down the road when clicked. I attempted to implement `var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster()` but it will make my animation not appear. Is there a way to allow raycaster to work here or will I have to make functions `getMouse3D()` and `getMouse2D()`.

This is the initialize function along with the shoot function. The code block for the sphere and the clock are commented out.

```
$(function() {


    var spheres;
    //var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
    var intersects;
    var clock = new THREE.Clock();
    var delta = 0;
    
    var $trackingOverlay = $('#tracking-overlay');

    
        projector = new THREE.Projector();
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true, antialias: true } );
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        perspectiveCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(DEFAULT_VIEW_ANGLE, WIDTH / HEIGHT, PERSPECTIVE_NEAR, PERSPECTIVE_FAR);
        perspectiveCamera.position.set(DEFAULT_CAMERA_X, DEFAULT_CAMERA_Y, DEFAULT_CAMERA_Z);
        orthoCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(DEFAULT_ORTHO_LEFT, DEFAULT_ORTHO_RIGHT, DEFAULT_ORTHO_TOP, DEFAULT_ORTHO_BOTTOM, ORTHO_NEAR, ORTHO_FAR);
        pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
        pointLight.position.set(10, 50, 150);
        
        container = model;
        container.rotation.set(0.2,0,0);
        scene.add(container);
                
        /*spheres = [];
        viewport.addEventListener("click", event => {
            mouse.x = ( event.clientX / WIDTH ) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / HEIGHT ) * 2 + 1;
            raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, perspectiveCamera);
            intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([plane]);
            if (intersects.length == 0) return;
            shoot(intersects[0].point);
        }, false);
        */
        
                
        scene.add(pointLight);
        scene.add(perspectiveCamera);
        scene.add(orthoCamera);
        //scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 );
        setActiveCamera(); 
        

        // init controls
        setupControls();
        updateInputValues();
        toggleControls();

        // setup viewport
        viewport = document.getElementById('viewport');
        renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        renderer.setClearColor( 0xABCBFB, 0.2 );
        viewport.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // start the animation loop
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    
    function update()
    {
        
        /*delta = clock.getDelta();
        spheres.forEach(sphere => {
        sphere.position.addScaledVector(sphere.userData.direction, sphere.userData.speed * delta);
        if (sphere.position.z <= torus.position.z) sphere.userData.speed = 0; // stop, when we reached the plane
        }); 
        */

        renderer.render(scene, activeCamera);
        positionTrackingOverlay();

        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }

    function shoot(target) {
        let sphere = new THREE.Mesh();
        sphere.material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ color: "#00ff00" });
        sphere.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5);
        sphere.position.copy(road.position);
        sphere.userData.direction = target.sub(road.position).normalize();
        sphere.userData.speed = 20;
        scene.add(sphere);
        spheres.push(sphere);
    }
```

Comment: Please narrow down your code to just include the segment where you're running into problems. Creating a [minimal example is very important](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can quickly reproduce your problem. 350 lines of code is asking too much for people to parse through.

Comment: I made the edits to only include the parts with the problem. All of my code will run if I keep var raycaster commented out.

Comment: I've never seen a Mesh be initiated like this. Have you tried doing `THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)` instead of assigning each later? I recommend you comment out the lines in your `shoot()` function and un-comment them one at a time until you run into the one that's making your animation disappear. For example, I don't see how `road` is being created, so it may not exist, thus breaking your animation.